# What is the best way to check if time is within a certain minute?

Tags: python

I want to write a simple python script which will check to see if it's 2 minutes before a given hour/minute, and then call my function either everyday or for a given date at the given time.

The script will run every minute in a cronjob.

So the two cases to execute myfunction():

10:55 everyday
10:55 on 9/28/2012

But I am having trouble determining when it's 2 minutes prior to the given hour/minute using datetime. Also, how to determine everyday vs just on a given day?

```
mydate = datetime(2012, 09,28, 10,55)
check = mydate - datetime.now()    # gives you a timedelta

if check < datetime.timedelta(minutes=2):
     run_myfunction()
```

The above sees if it's within 2 minutes, and if it is, then runs the myfunction(). The problem with the above code is that if the mydate has passed, the myfunction() will still run. Also, this requires that a specific date to be specified. How would one allow the check for everyday rather than 9/28/2012?

Comment: why don't you let the script run everyday at 10:55 by the cronjob?

Comment: Thanks guys, I just went with doing a check with minutes=0. Guess I should have thought about this more before I posted!

Answer (score 9):

```
now = datetime.now()
mystart = now.replace(hour=10, minute=55, second=0)
myend = mystart + timedelta(minutes=2)
if mystart <= mydate < myend:
    # do your stuff
```

Comment: Note that as of recent editions at least, the parameters should be hour, minute, second (without the s) (see for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/datetime-replace-function-in-python/)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest unless the documentation has been retroactively updated a la Star Wars, your statement is correct all the way back to Python 2.7.  Thanks for pointing it out, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
mydate = datetime(2012, 09,2, 10,55)
current_date = datetime.now()
check = mydate - current_date    # gives you a timedelta

if mydate > current_date and check < datetime.timedelta(minutes=2):
     run_myfunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be hackish, but you can use `.total_seconds()` to construct a range:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

then = datetime(2012, 9, 18, 16, 5)
now = datetime.now()
delta = timedelta(minutes=10)

if 0 < (then - now).total_seconds() < delta.total_seconds():
    # ...
```

That way, if `then - now` is a negative `timedelta`, `total_seconds()` will return a negative number and make your condition `False`.

Comment: `total_seconds()` is available since Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

For the everyday part, you can use

```
reference = datetime.datetime(2012,9,18,23,55,00)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = reference.replace(year=now.year,month=now.month,day=now.day)
```

For the time difference:

```
delta = (now-today)
lapse = delta.days * 86400 + delta.seconds
if abs(lapse) <= 2*60:
    run_function()
```